# mysql query error 1054 - unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql

I failed to run a query in mysql. Deliberately I dont want to do `select id from roles`...

the query

```
select rtu.role_id
from roles r 
where id =(select role_id 
           from roles_to_user rtu 
           where user_id=1)
```

error

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'rtu.role_id' in 'field list'
```

desc roles_to_user:

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| role_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

desc roles:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(80) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use columns from a inner select outside it like this. Select `r.id` instead

```
select r.id
from roles r 
where id = (select role_id 
            from roles_to_user rtu 
            where user_id = 1)
```

BTW that will fail if the inner select returns more than 1 record. Use a `join` instead

```
select rtu.role_id
from roles r 
inner join roles_to_user rtu on rtu.role_id = r.id
where rtu.user_id = 1
```

Comment: beside syntax, is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Yes. The 1st query fails for multiple roles for a user. The 2nd returns a record for every row. For many records there could be a performance difference, but that could be examined using `explain select ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your alias rtu is only available in your subquery, not in the main one.